# What other efficient ways of encrypting a long text besides Vigenére Ciphers that also has compression without additional libraries?

Tags: javascript, encryption, caesar-cipher, vigenere

I have a 8000 character block of text and I want to encrypt this string without increasing the character count and adding additional libraries. I'm using javascript to do this.

The closest thing I came up with for encryption is creating a custom javascript function to implement a Vigenére Cipher to this block of text along with an encryption key. I understand that this can easily be cracked, but my main goal is to:

- encrypt a block of text with a secret key/password
- keep this block of 8000 character text under 8000 and provides a way to compress the string data
- not use any external javascript libraries
- do everything in pure javascript

Comment: What have you tried?  Implementing a Vigenére Cipher should be fairly straightforward if that's what you actually want.  Or are you looking for an alternative to it?

Comment: Yes I'm looking to see what other available options I might have. Yes its pretty straightforward to write up a function for it, but I was wondering if there was something similar but also provides compression.

Comment: I imagine you'd have to have a fairly small input character set (A-Z, ASCII or some such) in order to add compression, but that's just my inexperienced thinking.

Comment: Compress *before* encrypting, that way you get better compression *and* you can  encrypt with AES instead of a toy.

Comment: @JamesKPolk compress with what? and the purpose is to use a toy, basic encryption without the need of any additional libraries. i just want to obfuscate the text using only simple encryption with the ability to decrypt with a secret. only a vigenere cipher comes to mind.

Comment: Ok, there's nothing wrong with a toy, I didn't realize this was a learning exercise. So what would you use to compress the ciphertext after the Vigenere? Or do you just need it to be compressible, but you don't need to do the compression yourself?

Comment: A built in javascript text compressor would be nice if such a thing exists. I just want to be able to compress 10,000 characters while also providing a way to encrypt it without the use of additional javascript libraries.